# How to interchange rows in iterative methods for solving linear system?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

In all resources about iterative methods (e.g. Jacobi method) there's information that if there are zeros on main diagonal, rows or columns must be interchanged, but what exact algorithm should be used for that? The naive method of finding row with maximum element and interchanging it, won't always work, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In full generality, this is the problem of finding a perfect matching in a bipartite graph. Here, the graph has two parts $R$ and $C$ of size $n$ corresponding to the rows and columns, with an edge from $i\in R$ to $j\in C$ if $A_{ij} \ne 0$.

We can find a perfect matching, assuming it exists, using the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm on this graph. Most sources on Ford-Fulkerson solve the equivalent maximum-flow problem, and many assume that the graph is weighted and we want the maximum-weight matching. But you can find a description of the unweighted matching problem on http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/, which shouldn't be too far removed from the matrix setting (especially since they store the bipartite graph as an adjacency matrix anyway).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, but complexity of this algorithm is pretty high, so I guess it's not really used in practice. So how is it done usually? We just use naive method?

Comment: The worst-case complexity is pretty high, but the worst-case complexity *has* to be high: if you're handed a permutatation matrix, you might need $O(n^2)$ time to find the ones. I think in a typical case where only a few entries are $0$, implementing this algorithm would be fairly cheap: it would just tell you "okay, find an entry below this one with a nonzero value" and maybe for the last few rows this wouldn't work out and you'd have to do a second swapping step.